# Degree of freedom of a BEC

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, degrees-of-freedom

I would like to know how many degrees of freedom an atomic gas has. What about the Bose-Einstein condensation from that gas?

Comment: presumably 6 per molecule

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Ok, but all of them are in the same quantum state. It suggests the whole system has only 6 degrees of freedom.

Comment: @peterh Not in a gas...  Put another way: there is a reason why statistical physics is statistical.  Or maybe I just don't understand the first part of the question (which could very well be...)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I agree, I think this question is not so clear as for the first spot.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Hydrogen is a diatomic gas. Therefore it has 6 degrees of freedom. What about his Bose- Einstein condensate?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question then. Maybe it's just semantics but hydrogen is not a gas: gas is a state of matter, like solid or liquid.  A clould of $10^{15}$ molecules of $H_2$ might be a gas, but a single molecule is not a gas as I understand the word.

Comment: I'm sorry for this. In my language the two words (gas and cloud) are synonymous. What I want to know is whether a BEC has the same degrees of freedom as the original cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the type of gas and on its temperature.

If the gas is made of single atoms like $^{87}Rb$ or $^{39}K$ (typical atoms that are Bose-Condensed, since you are asking), then it as $3$ degrees of freedom - motion along $x, y,$ and $z$.

If the constituents are diatomic molecules, like $H_2$, then the two atoms could also rotate about the centre of mass, which introduces $2$ new degrees of freedom - clockwise, counterclockwise.

They can also vibrate, as if they were connected by a spring - this introduces $2$ new modes, for in-phase and out-of-phase vibration.

Evidence for the $3$ translational, $2$ rotational and $2$ vibrational degrees of freedom is in the plot of heat capacities (below), where it can also be seen that, when present, the latter two modes only get unlocked (*unfrozen*) at higher temperatures. This is because the energy associated with that motion is on the order of several $\gg k_B T$:

[image]

So even it you made a BEC of diatomic molecules, you will not see the rotational and vibrational modes, as you are too cold. 
 This is why a very active field is the one of *cold molecules*, where you bind two (cold) atoms together with, e.g., a Feshbach resonance, so as for the energy of the mode to be much lower and hence accessible.